# Updating old Java Chatbot program to use Discord

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a long-term Java project that I use to run a Google Hangouts bot using Smack (it was first an AIM bot).  I would like to incorporate Discord as well (not instead) but it looks like I need to start using an IDE and Maven or Gradle.  I am not sure how to start incorporating that into my current code.

In my current setup, I have my code on a (private) GitHub repo.  I edit the source on my laptop in a text editor (Kate) and then I run it in a terminal on my raspberry pi that runs the bot.  I run the bot with a shell script with compile and run commands that use a bunch of jars I have locally.

What is the easiest way for me to incorporate Discord capability?  Do I need to start using a real IDE?  Will I still be able to run everything via the terminal on the pi?

Comment: Who told you you need an IDE to use a software library? If you read that somewhere, close that browser tab and never go back; it's a bad tutorial if it depends on a specific IDE.

Comment: I don't know whether it's necessary, but the installation guide on the GitHub shows IntelliJ and Eclipse: https://github.com/Discord4J/Discord4J

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I think it a wise decision to use IntelliJ or Eclipse if you want to Java programming.